# How do I install any package globally?

Tags: package, global

How can I make a package to work on every project I created without installing it on every project directory?

Comment: What do you mean package? Is it npm package or others? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to npm packages then in the terminal

type: `npm i <package name<n>> -g`

then to access them

type: `npm link <package name<n>>`